# Field Level Encryption in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We use Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 that we host ourselves (not the Online version). We have a certain custom field that we need to encrypt on the database level (probably using the symmetric encryption within SQL database). This way nobody can break into our database and query that sensitive information.

Is it possible to do this within Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in a plugin for string or memo type attributes. Register plugin steps on the **pre create and pre update messages** for the entity. Your plugin can encrypt strings that pass the plugin pipeline. String attributes in the Target entity (found in the `InputParameters` collection in the `IPluginExecutionContext` object) can directly be modified.

When the encrypted field only needs to be accessed in web forms, it is enough to register a third plugin step on the **post retrieve message** for the same entity. In the `OutputParameters` collection the retrieved entity can be found. The string attribute can be decrypted on the fly.